# BiDirectional graph converted to multiple single directional graphs with Networkx in Python

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, edges

I am pretty new to python and specifically Networkx. I am attempting to take a Bidirectional graph in networkx, and from that create multiple single directional graphs that all stem from nodes that intersect a boundary.

The picture below is the structure of the graph with the nodes labeled that intersect with my boundary.

[image: This is the structure of the entire graph]

What I want to do is create multiple graphs like this (only showing nodes 1 and 5 as examples, need to do all)

[image]

As you can see I don't want any edges returning to nodes that they have already been at, thus the single direction.

I think I would do something along the lines of

```
for x in G.nodes:
    G.out_edges(x)
```

which returns

```
[(1, 2)]
[(2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 1)]
[(3, 4), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 2)]
[(4, 3)]
[(5, 2)]
[(6, 2)]
[(7, 3)]
[(8, 3)]
```

in order to get some basic structure. I am just a little confused and could use any ideas on how I could construct these graphs so it would work for each node. In the true example I need to do, there are 100s of these graphs that need to be created. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you can solve this by some graph traversal. How about using [`dfs_labeled_edges`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_labeled_edges.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_labeled_edges) with specified source and only using "forward" edges?